# Elasticsearch Date Histogram for Unique Mac Address per day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using Elasticsearch (with Tire) and need to create a facet which outputs a statistics about daily unique mac addresses per day, week, month. I've been running into problems getting it working correctly.

I need to mean and total figures and couldn't get it working with the date_histogram facet:

```
def self.search_stats params
  tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 50) do |s|
    filter = []
    filter << { :terms => { ... }}

    s.facet('uniques') do
      date :created_at, :interval => 'day', value_field: 'mac.sortable'
      facet_filter :and, filter
    end
  end
end
```

That gave an error: "Failed to parse source... "

In the end, I've been trying to use a script to get it done but that's not really working out as I can't figure out how to group the values.

I been using:

```
date :created_at, value_script: "doc['mac.sortable'].values.size()", interval: 'day'
```

Obvs. size() is wrong as I need the unique values.

My mapping looks like this:

```
mapping do
  ...
  indexes :mac, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
    raw: {type: 'string', index: 'analyzed'},
    sortable: {type: 'string', index: :not_analyzed}
  }
  ...
end
```

I don't really want to use a script field at all because of the memory usage warning.

How can I get my macs grouped and sorted daily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting unique values in a distributed environment is difficult. In order to get completely accurate counts, you need to count all unique values on every node, then merge all of those counts into a single list on one node.

For fields with low cardinality this approach can work just fine, but fields with high cardinality will end up using enormous amounts of memory and will more than likely fail.

There are two options available, but you have to choose between speed and accuracy. You can either:

1. Get slow accurate counts using map-reduce
2. Get fast estimated counts using Elasticsearch

The estimation approach uses the [HyperLogLog algorithm (PDF)](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlFuGaMe07.pdf) which estimates how many unique items are in a set.

With the new aggregations framework available in Elasticsearch 1.0, there are plans to support HLL via the `cardinality` aggregation. Currently the code is not in the main repository but can be seen on: https://github.com/jpountz/elasticsearch/tree/feature/term_count_aggregations

A [HyperLogLog facet](https://github.com/pearson-enabling-technologies/elasticsearch-approx-plugin) is available as a plugin for Elasticsearch but it hasn't been updated for recent versions. There is also this newly released [cardinality plugin](https://github.com/algolia/elasticsearch-cardinality-plugin) which uses HLL. I haven't used either plugin so can't vouch for them, but these look like your only options until official support for HLL is added to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Hmmm, in some ways I'm glad it's actually more complex than expected - was wondering why I was finding it so tricky. We're going to need both accuracy and speed as it has a bill-point. Firing up a hadoop cluster today funnily enough, will see what we can get from that. However, I'd rather rely on just ES. Am running 0.95 though which doesn't seem compatible with either plugin. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can read: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/count-elasticsearch/

```
POST /access/search/_search
{
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "daily" : { 
            "date_histogram" : {"field":"date", "interval" : "day"},
            "aggs" :
                {
                     "query_count" : {"cardinality" : {"field" : "q"} }
                 }
                    }
               }
}
```

Comment: Using both now. We managed to get the first query done with MySQL and some handy indexing across the proper cols. Query time not dissimilar to ES either. Quite nice to use MySQL properly and not rely on fancy new tools ;) Having said that, we had to use aggs for a query with 50million rows...

Comment: Yes it's often better to rely on solid techno. And can be even faster if you execute all the "sub ES queries" in parallel (but I guess ES has a strong multi thread management, compared to mysql ^^). BTW this new aggregator framework is really cool !